# Считать цвет ячейки в Excel используя openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

С помощью Python и openpyxl я открыл .xlsx файл, считал данные с нужного мне листа.  Далее с помощью  `ws.cell(row=2, column=4).value` возвращаю текст ячейки.

Подскажите, как вернуть цвет фона ячейки?

Я делаю так:

```
ws.cell(row=2, column=4).fill.bgColor
```

Результат:

```
<openpyxl.styles.colors.Color object>
Parameters:
rgb=None, indexed=64, auto=None, theme=None, tint=0.0, type='indexed'
```

Но это ячейка точно покрашена в зеленый (глазами вижу).

Почему я получаю неверный параметр цвета в rgb не используя xlrd?

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь атрибутом `cell.fill.fgColor.value`:

```
In [77]: ws.cell(row=2, column=3).fill.fgColor.value
Out[77]: 'FFFFEB9C'
```

или:

```
In [84]: ws["C2"].fill.fgColor.value
Out[84]: 'FFFFEB9C'
```

Answer (score 0):

Помогла подсказка stackoverflow.com
Фон смог вернуть с помощью fill.start_color.index